# Zod refine unknown error message when applied to more paths

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form, zod, shadcnui

I need to validate two fields "at the same time" using zod refine and react-hook-form. User has three inputs one, two, three and sum of values two, three must be equal to one, the error must be displayed in both two and three fields and must disappear from both fields when the condition is achieved. I tried with setting path to these fields, but the error message is displayed only in field two and is "unknown" not "fieldTwo plus...". Could you help with that?
Schema:

```js
const schema = z.object({
  fieldOne: z.number(),
  fieldTwo: z.number(),
  fieldThree: z.number(),
}).refine(data => data.fieldTwo + data.fieldThree === data.fieldOne, {
  message: "fieldTwo plus fieldThree must be equal to fieldOne",
  path: ["fieldTwo", "fieldThree"],
});
```

I also tried using superRefine with adding two ctx.addIssue for path fieldTwo and fieldThree and the error is displayed correctly in both fields, but when the condition is achieved the error message disappears only from edited field not from both:

```js
  .superRefine((args, ctx) => {
    if (args.fieldTwo + args.fieldThree !== args.fieldOne) {
      ctx.addIssue({
        code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
        path: ["fieldTwo"],
        message: "fieldTwo plus fieldThree must be equal to fieldOne",
      });
      ctx.addIssue({
        code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
        path: ["fieldThree"],
        message: "fieldTwo plus fieldThree must be equal to fieldOne",
      });
    }
  });
```

Edit: minimal react code example

```js
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { DialogFooter } from "@/components/ui/dialog";
import { Form, FormControl, FormField, FormItem, FormLabel, FormMessage } from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { z } from "zod";

const Test = () => {
  const schema = z
    .object({
      fieldOne: z.coerce.number(),
      fieldTwo: z.coerce.number(),
      fieldThree: z.coerce.number(),
    })
    .superRefine((args, ctx) => {
      if (args.fieldTwo + args.fieldThree !== args.fieldOne) {
        ctx.addIssue({
          code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
          path: ["fieldTwo"],
          message: "fieldTwo + fieldThree must = fieldOne",
        });
        ctx.addIssue({
          code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
          path: ["fieldThree"],
          message: "fieldTwo + fieldThree must = fieldOne",
        });
      }
    });

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof schema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(schema),
  });

  const onSubmit = (values: z.infer<typeof schema>) => {
    console.log("SUBMIT::", values);
  };

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-8">
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="fieldOne"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem className="grid grid-cols-4 items-center !mt-2 gap-4">
              <FormLabel className="text-right">FieldOne</FormLabel>
              <div className="col-span-3">
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder="Enter fieldOne" {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage className="mt-2" />
              </div>
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="fieldTwo"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem className="grid grid-cols-4 items-center !mt-2 gap-4">
              <FormLabel className="text-right">FieldTwo</FormLabel>
              <div className="col-span-3">
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder="Enter fieldTwo" {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage className="mt-2" />
              </div>
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="fieldThree"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem className="grid grid-cols-4 items-center !mt-2 gap-4">
              <FormLabel className="text-right">FieldThree</FormLabel>
              <div className="col-span-3">
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder="Enter fieldThree" {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage className="mt-2" />
              </div>
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <DialogFooter>
          <Button type="submit" className="w-1/4">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </DialogFooter>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: `path` is singular. You can have only one error message, at one field, produced from `refine`. Either refine twice, or use `superRefine` as you tried. That the error message doesn't disappear would be a problem (possibly bug) in your form validation code/framework, not with zod. If you need help with that, please post the entire react code.

Comment: @Bergi edited to shoe superRefine, but posting react code is way too long. I'm using shadcn form with [input](https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/input#form) which uses react hook form. FormMessage is using useFormField() to check if the error is not undefined, if so it shows a <p> with error

Comment: Try parsing some sample input data directly with your zod schema. I'm sure it'll return the correct (number of) errors. If they don't go away in your UI, this is a react hooks problem. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Bergi you are right, number of errors is correct (and it was), but only one err msg disappears from UI. Edited the post with simple example, and I'll try to find the issue in ui